# Debugging Haskell read function

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm writing a simple AI decision system to play a 20 questions style of game. If the program is unable to guess the correct answer, it will ask for a question to use to distinguish the answer and it will store that question in a tree. It reads the tree in from the file system at the start of the program and writes it back out at the end.

I'm having a lot of problems with the serialization code in Haskell. I'm getting the error "Prelude read: no parse". What's going on? Here's my code:

```
import Data.Char
import System.IO

-- Defines a type for a binary tree that holds the questions and answers
data Tree a = 
        Answer String | 
        Question String (Tree a) (Tree a)
        deriving (Read, Show)

-- Starts the game running
main = do
        let filePath = "data.txt"
        fileContents <- readFile filePath
        animals <- return (read fileContents)
        putStrLn "Think of an animal. Hit Enter when you are ready.  "
        _ <- getLine
        ask animals
        writeFile filePath (show animals)

-- Walks through the animals tree and ask the question at each node
ask :: Tree a -> IO ()
ask (Question q yes no) = do
        putStrLn q
        answer <- getLine
        if answer == "yes" then ask yes
                           else ask no
ask (Answer a) = do
        putStrLn $ "I know! Is your animal a " ++ a ++ "?"
        answer <- getLine
        if answer == "yes" then computerWins
                           else playerWins

computerWins = do putStrLn "See? Humans should work, computers should think!"

playerWins = do putStrLn "TODO"
```

And here's the data file I'm using:

```
Question "Does it live in the water?"
        ((Question "Does it hop?") (Answer "frog") (Answer "fish"))
        (Answer "cow")
```

Comment: `Tree` doesn't need a type qualifier - you can easily replace all `Tree a` with `Tree`, without changing your program behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` is not intended to handle things like extra parentheses robustly. Your code works for me with the following data file:

```
Question "Does it live in the water?"
        (Question "Does it hop?" (Answer "frog") (Answer "fish"))
        (Answer "cow")
```

Comment: @stomcavage: You might be better off in the long run using something like [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.0.1) for reading your data files, since it will give you clearer error messages and allow for more variation in the formatting (although I'm not sure you'd want your original version to be considered valid anyway, since it suggests that the contructor `Question` takes a single `String` argument).

Comment: I just want to agree with Travis Brown that you really, really want to use a parser.  Parsec's pretty common, but I prefer uu-parsinglib.  http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uu-parsinglib